# How debug non-xcode process with XCode 4.6.2 and lldb?

Tags: macos, xcode4.6, lldb

I have a process running (not an app) built with GNU make, clang, etc. with full debug info. I want to attach to it with lldb and a GUI debugger that shows me source code, variable bindings etc.

Is there a way to do this with lldb on OS X 10.8 with XCode 4.6.2 or any other tool (e.g. a working lldb mode for Emacs)?

I tried attaching with XCode 4.6.2 but it only shows disassembly and I found no way to tell it where to look for source code. Someone on SO suggested editing the scheme and setting custom working directory but the folder selection icon is disabled. Another suggested Add Files to ... but that did not help.

Attaching from Terminal.app with plain lldb shows line numbers and source file names (but not pathnames). I could not find a way to tell lldb where to look for source code either.

In gbd, on the command line, I can use the dir command to tell it where the source is located and that makes the list command work. This makes XCode show the source if I tell XCode to use gbd (still possible, from the "Attach To Process/By Process Identifier (PID) or Name" menu), but gdb support is being removed from XCode so this method will soon stop working.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `target.source-map` setting in lldb to provide a mapping.  If you built the program on your own system, I'm not sure why this would be necessary -- it only comes up if you build your program with the source code in one location (`/tmp/original-directory`) and then you move the source to a different location (`/tmp/new-directory`) and try to debug.  More commonly it comes up if you're building on one system and then you move everything over to a second system for debugging but don't copy the source files into the same location.

Anyway, http://lldb.llvm.org/lldb-gdb.html shows an example of how this is used but in short,

```
(lldb) settings set target.source-map /buildbot/path /my/path
```

would tell lldb to substitute all occurrences of `/buildbot/path` to `/my/path` when it is looking for source code files.  You can put this setting in your `~/.lldbinit` file to make it persist.

There is not a direct equivalence of gdb's `dir` command yet but you can usually accomplish the same thing easily enough this way.

Ah wait I just saw the Xcode 4.2.3 bit... That's a very old version of lldb. Strongly recommend upgrading to Xcode 4.6 if you're going to use lldb - I don't remember the lldb back in Xcode 4.2 very well...

Comment: Thanks, I will try this. (The title had the wrong XCode version)

Comment: target.source-map did not work. One problem is that I do not know where lldb is trying (and failing) to find the sources. Also, a path map seems inherently useless in my case where all source files are located exactly at the same place as when the binary was built.

According to http://lldb.llvm.org/lldb-gdb.html there is still no equivalent to the gdb directory command.

Is there a way to tell XCode where to look?

Comment: When you're stopped in one of these functions which should have source code, try `image lookup -v -a ADDRESS`.  This will show you everything lldb knows about that address, including the full path to the source file.  It may be that lldb is finding it correctly but Xcode isn't displaying the source code -- you can try command line lldb (`xcrun lldb`) to confirm if that's the case.  NB: in newer lldb's a simpler way to do this is `source list -a ADDRESS` but I can't remember if that works in the lldb in Xcode 4.6.

Comment: Note:  lldb's `target.source-map` *is* a way to do the same thing.  gdb had a `pathname-substitution` setting that did the same thing.  The gdb `dir` command just says "when you're looking for a source file and fail, try looking in this directory here".  There isn't an exact equivalent of that in lldb but you can accomplish the same thing with `target.source-map`.

Comment: The lldb in XCode 4.6.2 (LLDB-179.5) does not take an -a option. It does take a -n SYMBOL option which is good enough for me.  This shows that lldb thinks my source files are like ROOT/foo.c and ROOT/../bar.c where ROOT is the root of my development folder (they are really located in various sub-directories).

Comment: My guess is that the debug info only contains the relative path that was passed to the C compiler (foo.c and ../bar.c, in this case) and that lldb blindly prepends its incorrect guess about root directory.  In this case pathname substitution seems useless and in either case very much different from the gdb directory command (which does work in this case).

Comment: Interesting.  I can't imagine how this was built unless your build system moved the files to ROOT before compiling them (and then removed them again).  Otherwise the debug information from the compiler should point to the full pathname where the file is located.  You're right, lldb's path substitution won't handle this correctly -- but I would suggest looking at how you build your project and maybe think about making some adjustments to that ... if that's not the case, you may have an interesting compiler bug (this is built with clang, right?).  I've never seen that behavior though...

Comment: Can you do this within EMACS?

Answer (score 0):

Many years later... the first useful debugger that can handle our code on OS X is VSCODE (currently VSCODE 1.9.1, with the ms-vscode.cpptools 0.10.1) from Microsoft. That was unexpected.